# Linux shortcut to screenshot directly to clipboard (Arch linux, xclip, gnome-screenshot)

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

I'm trying to add a keyboard shortcut to be able to automatically screenshot an active window to the clipboard I'm trying this line of code right now `gnome-screenshot -w | xclip -selection clipboard` but it doesn't work

ps: yes I am writing this line in the shortcut section of gnome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gnome-screenshot -w` command doesn't write anything to standard output, so you can't pipe it to another program. In any case, you don't need to, see `man gnome-screenshot`:

```
   -c, --clipboard
          Send the grab directly to the clipboard.
```

So all you need is `gnome-screenshot -cw`.